# iMac runs warm?

Tags: mac, temperature, cooling

New iMac, mentioned in another question is warm to the touch. Is this normal? A yes or no answer based on personal experience please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warm to the touch yes, too hot to touch no.

Comment: Most iMacs have done this, they crank the fan down so it's quiet. People hardly ever feel the warmth of their computer, but an annoyingly loud computer is heard by everyone in the room.

Comment: Is it warm enough to affect machine durability?

Comment: This is like if a laptop is warm to the touch.  Cooler is generally better, however I do not have data as to if this really effects component lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it runs hot - download [smcfancontrol](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/23049) or similar to crank the fans up.
iMacs appear to be tuned to be quiet but hot at the moment.